# How to search local storage for specific information submitted by a form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

This is for a student directory project. Basically I am submitting a form of student info on one page of HTML, saving the info to an object of key value pairs to an array that will hold multiple of these objects, then displaying that info on another HTML page acting as the directory. I also need to make a search page on a separate HTML page, which will need to search the array of objects for a matching last name value then display any students info with that last name on the same page.

I just need help with the javascript code to search the array of objects for the matching last name values in each object, then displaying if it matches.

Here is the code I have for the search and display function:

```
const searchStudents = e => {
    let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('studentList'));
    var result = document.getElementById('results');
    list.forEach(data => {
        if (document.getElementById('search') == data.lastname) {
            result.innerHTML += `
                            <tr>
                                <td>${data.firstname}</td>
                                <td>${data.lastname}</td>
                                <td>${data.address}</td>
                                <td>${data.city}</td>
                                <td>${data.state}</td>
                                <td>${data.zipcode}</td>
                                <td>${data.email}</td>
                                <td>${data.phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                `;
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is what the form and intended display location looks like on the HTML page:

```
            <div class="container">
                <form action="search.html" method="GET" onsubmit="searchStudents(event);">
                    <p>
                        <label>Search: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                    </p>    
                </form>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="results">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of search element from the event you have passed through submit function.

```
const searchStudents = e => {
    let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('studentList'));
    var result = document.getElementById('results');
    list.forEach(data => {
        if (e.target.elements.search.value == data.lastname) {
            return result.innerHTML += `
                            <tr>
                                <td>${data.firstname}</td>
                                <td>${data.lastname}</td>
                                <td>${data.address}</td>
                                <td>${data.city}</td>
                                <td>${data.state}</td>
                                <td>${data.zipcode}</td>
                                <td>${data.email}</td>
                                <td>${data.phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                `;
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this did not change anything.

Comment: @birchwoody try adding return before result.innerHTML